# win10 Audio 5.1 channel config

Tags: winapi, audio

I'm trying to change the channel set(like stereo to 5.1), but every api I tried just failed.
Like `IDirectSound8::SetSpeakerConfig` which now is NOP, according to [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ee418050(v%3Dvs.85)).
now I'm trying `IAudioChannelConfig` interface, but somehow it failed again.
it just returns `E_NOINTERFACE`.
here's part of my code.

```
HRESULT get_chann_interface(IMMDevice *pEndpoint)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    PROPVARIANT *pActivationParams = NULL;  // set to NULL to activate IDeviceTopology
    IDeviceTopology *dev_topo;
    hr = pEndpoint->Activate(IID_IDeviceTopology, CLSCTX_ALL, pActivationParams,(void**)&dev_topo);
    if (hr < 0 || dev_topo == NULL)
    {
        err_out("IDeviceTopology activate failed: ", hr);
        exit(hr);
    }

    IConnector *iconn;
    hr = dev_topo->GetConnector(0, &iconn);// there is only 1 connector in the device topology
    if (hr < 0)
    {
        err_out("IConnector interface get failed: ", hr);
        exit(hr);
    }

    IPart *ipart;
    hr = iconn->QueryInterface(IID_IPart, (void **)&ipart);
    if (hr < 0)
    {
        err_out("IPart interface query failed: ", hr);
        exit(hr);
    }

    IAudioChannelConfig *ichann_config;
    hr = ipart->Activate(CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IAudioChannelConfig, (void **)&ichann_config);
    if (hr < 0)
    {
        err_out("IAudioChannelConfig interface Activate failed: ", hr);
        return(hr);
    }
    DWORD pdwConfig;
    hr = ichann_config->GetChannelConfig(&pdwConfig);
    if (hr<0)
        err_out("GetChannelConfig failed: ", hr);
    else
        cout<<"channel config:" << hex << pdwConfig << endl;

    SAFE_RELEASE(ichann_config)
    SAFE_RELEASE(ipart)
    SAFE_RELEASE(iconn)
    SAFE_RELEASE(dev_topo)
}
```

I just failed to activate `IAudioChannelConfig` interface.
anyone knows any reasons?
thanks in advance.

Comment: According to the document you provided, it says for Windows Vista and later versions, the speaker configuration is a system setting that should not be modified by an application. End users can set the speaker configuration through control panels.After a quick search, I found that for such changes, [more methods](https://appuals.com/how-to-configure-and-test-5-1-surround-sound-on-windows-10/) are based on the control panel modification.

Comment: yeah,I know, and that's why I trying using interface ['IAudioChannelConfig::SetChannelConfig '](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/windows/win32/api/devicetopology/nf-devicetopology-iaudiochannelconfig-setchannelconfig), which according to microsoft, should be supported after Windows Vista. But I just can't even activate the interface!

Comment: Can you provide [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? On the other hand, I don't think you can succeed in this way, please refer to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/187692f0-c71a-4317-98f9-77bcc6d67d08/changing-default-speaker-configuration-on-vista?forum=windowspro-audiodevelopment).